# Need help restructuring and/or refacoring this c++ code concerning inheritance between multiple classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

OK, Not sure on the terminology for what I'm trying to do so edits are very welcome.

I've got code such as this:

```
class CBaseItemTracker
{
public:
    CBaseItemTracker();
    void IncrementCount() { ++count; }

protected:
    int count;
};

class CDerivedItemTracker : CBaseItemTracker
{
public:
    CDerivedItemTracker();
    void Print() { printf("something:%d\ncount:%d\n", something, count); }

private:
    int something;
};

class CBaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass();

private:
    CItemTracker item;
};

class CDerivedClass : CBaseClass
{
public:
    CDerivedClass();
    CDerivedItemTracker GetDerivedItem();
private:
    CDerivedItemTracker derived_item;
};
```

What I would like to accomplish is that `CBaseClass::item` and `CDerivedClass::derived_item` are actually the same object such that:

1. Code within `CBaseClass` can update `item`
2. Code within `CDerivedClass` can update `derived_item` (and therby also update `item`)
3. Code external to `CDerivedClass` can retrieve a `CDerivedItemTracker` object that includes the `item` variable.

I feel like I am trying to do something that is fundamentally wrong but I'm not seeing a good way to resolve it.

Comment: Why not consolidate CItemTracker with CBaseClass? Do you absolutely have to have them separate? All you have in CItemTracker is just an integer.

Comment: So, you need a class hierarchy that can potentially have members of another class hierarchy. Is this right ?

Comment: You need a membervariable who's type can be overridden by a derived class, right? In other words, a virtual property or virtual member variable, which are the terms that you should search for online.

Comment: @sgtHale in the actual code CItemTracker is more complex (I dumbed it down for this question) and is re-used in other classes.  I would like to extend its use for one case but that one case happens to be in a derived class of another class that already implements it.

Comment: BTW: This indeed has nothing to do with multiple inheritance. MI is when a class has more than one baseclass, which is not the case here. I'd suggest you remove that from the topic and question text, as it doesn't help.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yeah, I knew it wasn't MI in the traditional sense but wasn't sure if what I was trying to do would be properly resolved using MI through refactoring which is why that was worded that way.  Removed from Title.  As for virtual member variables.  I believe that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: About constraint (3): do you mean CDerivedItemTra**ck**er ?  And when you say "include item" do you mean that the item is a subobject  of the derived item ?

Comment: @Christophe, yes and yes.  edited the question to be clearer later down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is that code within `CBaseClass` can update base member `item` and
code within `CDerivedClass` can update members `derived_item` as well as `item`.

## Is it a member access problem ?

The first two constraints are the basics of inhertance.

The only problem in your code is that you have `item` member as **`private`**.  This means that the derived classes won't have access to it.  Just change it to be **`protected`** instead:

```
class CBaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass();
protected:       //<===== derived classes will have direct acess to this member
    CItemTracker item;
};
class CDerivedClass : CBaseClass
{
public:
    CDerivedClass();
    CDerivedItemTracker GetDerivedItem();
private:    // you can leave it private, but if further dirved classe need access
            // make it protected as well, but then you should consider public inheritance 
            // so that the further derived also see the item. 
    CDerivedItemTracker derived_item;
};
```

Now the derived class sees both itmes.  In `GetDerivedItem()` you can choose which item to return.  But `item` and `derived_item` will remain unrelated, as your class definitions define two distinct members.

## Or is it about sharing a single (derived) item ?

The third requirement makes the things a little bit more complex.  I'm not 100% sure of your intentions.  But if the intention is to extend in a derived class an item of the base class, this wont be possible as such, due to C++ standard constraints on the object layout.

Fortunately there are two main alternatives:  templates or dynamic member.

### Template approach

The template approach should be considered if at compile time you do already make the choice of the member type.

```
template <class myitem>
class CBase
{
public:
    CBase() {}
protected:
    myitem item; 
};
template <class myitem>
class CDerived : CBase<myitem>
{
public:
    CDerived() {}
    myitem GetDerivedItem() { return item; }
};
```

You can use this as follows:

```
CBase<CBaseItem> b; 
CDerived<CDerivedItem> d;   
d.GetDerivedItem().Print();
```

The principle is that for object `d` in `CBase` would have a `CDerivedItem` item, even if you would only access to the subset of its public `CBaseItem` members.

### Dynamic approach

The dynamic approach doesn't use templates, but creates the item during the construction.

Here I present a simple implementation based on references, taking the luxury of some unused members.  A more space efficient pointer based variant with dynamic allocation of the item should be prefered whenever space is critical.

```
class CBase
{
public:
    CBase() : item(base_item) {}    // when lonesome object: uses its own item 

protected:
    CBase(CBaseItem &itm) : item(itm) {}  // when subovject of a derived class
    CBaseItem &item;
private: 
    CBaseItem base_item;            // used only for non derived CBase object.  
};
class CDerived : CBase
{
public:
    CDerived() : CBase(derived_item) {} // Tell the base class that there's already an item to be used. 
    CDerivedItem GetDerivedItem() { return derived_item; }
         // we can use item as well: it'll be the CBaseItem subobject of derived_item
private:
    CDerivedItem derived_item;
};
```

ATTENTION:  for this to work you need public inhertance between item classes (  `class CDerivedItem : public CBaseItem`)

The difficulty here, is that base classes are constructed first.  So you have to provide to the base class constructor the item reference that it has to use.  If inadvertently you'd forget, the base would think it is a free object and will use a separate item.  THis is why I'd suggest to use the template approach if possible.

Comment: wouldn't this create 2 objects (derived_item and item)?  And if so, wouldn't I also then need to copy item's values into the derived_item object whenever derived_item is used or retrieved?

Comment: it creates 2 objects (derived_item and base_item), but only one of if would be used.  `item` is a reference (`&`) to the object to be used, not an additional object. This is why no copying is needed.

Comment: I think you edited to expand your answer while I was contemplating this and I commented without refreshing.  After reading the expanded answer, my intent is definitely in the category of "to extend in a derived class an item of the base class".  I think that either solution (template or dynamic) would work for me but I'll have to do some more analysis of my entire codebase to see which one I need to go with.  Thanks, answer accepted!